# Can we use barcode scanner as QRcode Scanner?

Tags: ios, objective-c, qr-code

I am making an app with QRcode and I have a prior code that uses barcode scanner. Can modify it as QRcode scanner too?

Thanks

Comment: Yes,we can do so. All we have to do is change the CIdetector type:

CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeQRCode context:nil options:@{CIDetectorAccuracy:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh}];

Comment: You should provide more details about which barcode scanner you are currently using, there are plenty, including several implementations in iOS and many more as external libraries.

Comment: I am using the default detector code provided by Apple.

Comment: got the answer @jcaron. Although thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CIdetector type: CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeQRCode context:nil options:@{CIDetectorAccuracy:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh}];
```

Change the CIdetector type to CIDetectorTypeQRCode.

Comment: Thanks! This is what i needed.

Comment: Is there any other way around apart from this one?

Comment: Like By not using CIDetector?

Answer (score 1):

To scan barcode and qrcode you can use below code snippet

add this in your view controller

```
let supportedCodeTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]
```

then add this function in your viewcontroller

```
    func startVideoCapture(){
        // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDevice class to initialize a device object and provide the video as the media type parameter.
        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

        do {
            // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous device object.
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

            // Initialize the captureSession object.
            captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

            // Set the input device on the capture session.
            captureSession?.addInput(input)

            // Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session.
            let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
            captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

            // Set delegate and use the default dispatch queue to execute the call back
            captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = supportedCodeTypes

            // Initialize the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer.
            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            videoPreviewLayer?.frame = self.qrCodeView.bounds
            self.qrCodeView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
            self.qrCodeView.clipsToBounds = true
            // Start video capture.
            captureSession?.startRunning()
            qrCodeFrameView = UIView()

//            if let qrCodeFrameView = qrCodeFrameView {
//                qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
//                qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
//                self.qrCodeView.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView)
//                self.qrCodeView.bringSubview(toFront: qrCodeFrameView)
//            }

        } catch {
            // If any error occurs, simply print it out and don't continue any more.
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }
```

then in your `viewWillAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        self.startVideoCapture()
}
```

and don't forget to check camera permission before call startVideoCapture